# No such file or directory error on --audit-policy-file flag

Tags: kubernetes, audit, kubeadm

I'm trying to enable audit option on my kubeadm based k8s. (v1.11.2)

but after I added `--audit-policy-file` flag on `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`, It won't start and print `no such file or directory` error.

This is my kube-apiserver.yaml file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
 ...
    - --audit-policy-file=/etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml
    - --audit-log-path=/var/log/kubernetes
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-apise...
...
```

and my error printed.

```
error: loading audit policy file: failed to read file path "/etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml": open /etc/kubernetes/audit-policy.yaml: no such file or directory
```

I double checked the path and it was all fine.

Is this some kind of bug of kubeadm? I need your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `audit-policy.yaml` file to the root path of the master node and then edit the given path in `audit-policy-file` also.

```
 - --audit-policy-file=audit-policy.yaml
```

Comment: Issue solved. My `kube-apiserver` is running as a pod so i should mount it first before enable the option.... LOL

Comment: What is the root path of the master node?

Comment: can you give more details please about the solution? Mount what first?

Answer (score 0):

Create a volume and mounts for your audit policy file location in your kube-api manifest. 
Something like this.

```
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /var/lib/k8s_audit/
  name: data

volumes:
- hostPath:
  path: /var/lib/k8s_audit
  type: DirectoryOrCreate
  name: data
```